# sqlite trigger on delete update tuple with value from another table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers, sql-update

I have two tables: 
Customer (id, name, advisorID) and 
Employee (id, name, managerID)

When an employee is deleted from table Employee, how to make trigger that **update** Customer advisorID to the value of the deleted employees managerID?

So far I have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateAdvisor BEFORE DELETE ON Employee
   BEGIN
      UPDATE Customer set Customer.advisorID = Employee.managerID 
      from Employee
      WHERE Employee.managerID IN(
          SELECT managerID
          FROM Employee)
```

Thanks for helping!!

Comment: This makes little sense `WHERE Employee.managerID IN(
          SELECT managerID
          FROM Employee)`. It will obviously be true for all Employee records. The question is: what is the link between an Employee record and a Customer record. They share the same id? Or how are they linked?

Comment: The EmployeeID in Employee is the advisorID in customer. Make more sense @trincot

Answer (score 1):

The UPDATE statement works on a single table; you have to look up the new value with a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
UPDATE Customer
SET advisorID = (SELECT managerID
                 FROM Employee
                 WHERE Employee = OLD.EmployeeID)
...
```

Furthermore, you want to update only those customers that actually have the to-be-deleted employee as advisor:

```
...
WHERE advisorID = OLD.EmployeeID;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked great!

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateAdvisor BEFORE DELETE ON employee
BEGIN
UPDATE customer
SET advisorID = (SELECT managerID FROM employee WHERE employeeID = old.employeeID)
WHERE advisorID = old.employeeID;
END;
```